# ClassNotFoundException on android devices pre lollipop after update Android Studio, gradle and language level

Tags: java, android, android-studio-2.2

After updating Android Studio to 2.2.3, gradle to 2.2.3, and language level to 1_8 an exception occurs:

```
  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 3467
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.myapp.MyApp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myapp.MyApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapp-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.myapp-1, /system/lib]]
                                                 at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:516)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4317)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                              Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myapp.MyApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapp-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.myapp-1, /system/lib]]
                                                 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:975)
                                                 at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:511)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4317) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Application class in manifest:

```
    ...
    <application
    android:name="com.example.myapp.MyApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">
    ...
```

Gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled = true
    applicationId "com.example.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 0
    versionName "1"

    generatedDensities = []

    jackOptions {
        enabled true
        additionalParameters = ["jack.incremental": "true"]
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    incremental false

}


dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    dexInProcess true

}
```

MyApp class exist:

```
  public class MyApp extends MultiDexApplication {
  ....
```

This exception occurs only on devices pre lollipop

Comment: Hi, I'm experiencing this issue too, I was wondering if you have a solution already?

Comment: @Erick. Hi, I disabled java 8 and it is work. I use AndroidAnnotations library,   which conflicts with java 8. In future I would like replace AndroidAnnotations  by data binding and again use java 8.