# Unable to instantiate activity in 4.3 and 4.4 but possible in >5.0

Tags: android

I have implemented an app which is running on > Android 4.3 .. 
After a lot of changes it suddenly stops working < Android 5.0 but works on >Android 5.0 ..
Below you can see the error messages:

```
      E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.chickchat.chickchat/com.chickchat.chickchat.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.chickchat.chickchat.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.chickchat.chickchat-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.chickchat.chickchat-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.chickchat.chickchat.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.chickchat.chickchat-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.chickchat.chickchat-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.chickchat.chickchat" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>

    <application
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
```

Gradle.File

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.chickchat.chickchat"
    // Note: reducing to sdk 16 when removing UIAutomation
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Although there are a lot of questions with this type of Exception on stackoverflow I could find a solution for my problem...

Comment: **clean-Rebuild-run** you project

Comment: Have you changed packagename?

Comment: If it's working on Lollipop+ and complaining about missing classes before that, you'll need [multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html).

Comment: as @EugenPechanec said u may need to use Multidex. Can you post your gradle?

Comment: Clean-Rebuild-Run didnt work; multiDex is already enabled (gradle posted); yeah i changed package name

Comment: can you show your `build.gradle`

Comment: its the package com.vionym.chickchat ... as I said everything is working on > Android 5.0 
....
gradle is posted

Comment: Have you changed your package name in gradle file?

Comment: disable instant run for kitkat and below version **check this** [**multidex for kitkat and below**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44603205/7666442)

Comment: Just uninstall the already installed app. And delete app.debug file in the project folder . and then clean and rebuild.

Comment: @Ayox `multiDexEnabled true` is not enough to enable multidex below Lollipop. Read the whole thing https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#about

Comment: @NileshRathod Instant run is never used when deploying to a device below Lollipop. (I think it used to be possible in some old versions of the buiild plugin but not anymore.) Read https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#instant-run

Comment: compiling multidex:1.0.1 in dependencies and disable instant run doesnt help ...

Comment: @Ayox what is the java version u r using?

Comment: @Raghavendra Java 8.0 Update 131

Comment: @Ayox Quite not sure can u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42481456/classnotfoundexception-on-android-devices-pre-lollipop-after-update-android-stud

Comment: Does your application class extend from `MultiDexApplication` or does it implement the necessary `MultiDex.install(this)` -> https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle

Comment: Oh my f****** GOD THAAAAAAAAAAAAAANKS!!!!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a problem with multidex. Does your `Application` class extends from `MultiDexApplication` or does it implement the necessary `MultiDex.install(this)` operation.

[Configure Apps with Over 64K Methods](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle)